# Passing Parameters In API URLs in Django

Tags: api, django-views

I am playing around with API and this is my first API View
Please, help me understand where I am wrong.

I use this API 
    api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name},{country code}
and I wrote this view:

```
def forecast(request):
    url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q= {}&appid=My_Key'

cities = {'city': 'London', 'cod' : 826} 


city_weather = requests.get(url.format(cities)).json()

weather = {
    'temperature': city_weather['main']['temp'],# one parameter, just to check whethe it works

}

context = {'weather' : weather }
return render(request, 'weather/forecast.html')
```

This is very basic view like my first print("Hello, World!") , but id does not work at all))
  I will be thankful if you advise me some articles about this.
 Did not find answer here http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data you have saved into the view

```
context = {'weather' : weather }
return render(request, 'weather/forecast.html', context=context)
```

You can then access the data within the `context` variable inside your hmtl scirpt

```
<div>
{{ weather }}
</div>
```

Comment: Could you tell me please, does this code are correct for the particular case?:   
 * cities = {'city': 'London', 'cod' : 826} *


 * city_weather = requests.get(url.format(cities)).json()*

Comment: you are using your entire cities object as your argument to `format` when you probably just want one of its attributes.

Try something like

`requests.get(url.format(cities['cod'])).json()`